# Objective C - OBShapedButton and LongpressGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have got some special buttons(implemented with the subtype OBShapedButton, the button can have an transparent image and is only clickable on the size of the image) on my view. Now I have the idea to touch on the screen and move around. Everytime when I move over one of my buttons, I want to do something. How can I do that? I tried with the LongpressGestureRecognizer, but I dont know how I can get the objects I touch during the movement of my finger.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go take a look at `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).